# sensu triggering handler when command returns status 0

Tags: sensu

I'm trying to get sensu to send an email when disks get full, using a community disk checking plugin.  Sensu is triggering the handler even when the command that it executes returns a status of 0.

Here is the check_disk.json file

`{
  "checks": {
    "check_disk_usage": {
      "command": "/etc/sensu/plugins/check-disk.rb -c 42 -w 43",
      "handlers": ["debug", "email"],
      "subscribers": [ "disk_check" ],
      "interval": 30,
      "notification": "Disk Check failed",
      "occurrences": 5
    }
  }
}`

Here I run the command manually, notice success and status of zero:

`/etc/sensu/plugins/check-disk.rb -c 42 -w 43
CheckDisk OK: All disk usage under 43% and inode usage under 85%
[root@ip-10-9-66-239 conf.d]# echo $?
0`

Here is the relevant output in my sensu-client.log

`{"timestamp":"2015-06-17T20:03:43.079971+0000","level":"info","message":"publishing check result","payload":{"client":"portal","check":{"name":"check_disk_usage","issued":1434571422,"command":"/etc/sensu/plugins/check-disk.rb -c 42 -w 43","handlers":["debug","email"],"subscribers":["disk_check"],"interval":30,"notification":"Disk Check failed", "occurrences":5,"executed":1434571422,"duration":0.104,"output":"CheckDisk OK: All disk usage under 43% and inode usage under 85%\n","status":0}}}`

Any insights why sensu calls this a failure and does the notification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you get to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

A stated in the [docs](https://sensuapp.org/docs/latest/handlers) you can specify the severity that the handler will fire on.

```
{
  "handlers": {
    "statsd": {
      "type": "udp",
      "severities": [
        "warning",
        "critical",
        "unknown"
      ],
      "socket": {
        "port": 8125,
        "host": "statsd.service.consul"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is this does not work then post your handler config above as well.